# Short story about computer that saves human due to individual humans not having redundancy

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, artificial-intelligence

I read this short story online within the last three years (2014-2016).

Someone, a child(?), becomes trapped in an artificially maintained environment (garden room on a spaceship maybe?) during a crisis. The computer prioritizes saving the person over its normal tasks due to the person being non-redundant. The memory of the computer is erased at the end (power failure?) and it is unknown to others why the computer did what it did.

I think part of the story may have been presented as a running log file of the computers decisions.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: You've described the first episode of Red Dwarf (titled "The End"), but I doubt that's what you're talking about :)

Comment: The closest thing I could find is the "White Space Van Man" by  Darren Worrow